# Cocoa pods if install without version, it installed old package

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I pushed my library to cocoa pods. Now it has version 1.0.1:

```
pod spec lint USBDeviceSwift.podspec
pod trunk push USBDeviceSwift.podspec
```

All is ok, but if i install it without version:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testusb' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testusb

  pod 'USBDeviceSwift'

end
```

It installed old package 0.0.1. If I'm trying to push it again I get:

`[!] Unable to accept duplicate entry for: USBDeviceSwift (1.0.1)`

`'USBDeviceSwift', '~>1.0.1'` - works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem of your podspec, but how do you use it in your example project. Issuing `pod install` does not upgrade the version of the pod installed previously. The version saved in `Podfile.lock` is pulled down again instead. If you want to upgrade your pods, you should use `pod update [USBDeviceSwift]` explicitly.